# Doctrine 2 How do you create a onetoone relationship that allows one side to be null

Tags: php, sql, doctrine

Using Doctrine 2 I'm having trouble creating a onetoone relationship for an order to have a final IPN associated with it.  Of course the IPN wlil not generated until the PayPal transaction is concluded.

I tried to annotate the class with nullable=true but it complained that nullable is not a valid annotation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the annotation needs to be on the column that can be null and not on  the whole class
and if you want to use the nullable column as reference you will get unexpected results as there can be multiple null values